# Drawable resource file working only in large screen and not in smaller screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to fill only top half of my screen with below gradient

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="500sp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="40sp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="40sp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#9CA0DD"
                android:endColor="#ECB8B8"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

xml for layout

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/home_background_color">
</ScrollView>
```

This works fine with large screen devices but not with smaller screen , I am using "sp" instead of "dp" but the result is same
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach, since there is no way to specify a percentage in a drawable.

What you can do is to place a View behind the ScrollView, dedicated exclusively to the background. And use a Constraintlayout as your main one for more flexibility.

So for your drawable would be as next (notice it must be all in DPs and not SPs, and that your 'android:bottom=500sp' is fully removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="40dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#9CA0DD"
                android:endColor="#ECB8B8"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

For the main layout must be as next, (notice the tag 'app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF303030"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/home_background_color" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result is next:

[image]

As a side note, use the **"sp"** units only for fonts and never for graphics, for anything else that isn't a font (text size) use always **"dp"** units.

Comment: Will keep that in mind , thanks . Works like a charm